# Segmentation fault, shared library

Tags: c++

I get Segmentation Fault when I try to run my program. Can someone please help me find out what Im doing wrong?

Compiling with this:

```
    g++ sms_out.cpp -o sms_out
    g++ -c -fPIC SMSDispatch.cpp
    g++ -shared SMSDispatch.o -o libSMSDispatch.so
```

It should be a shared library and dynamic linking. I get Segmentation Fault when I try to run sms_out.

//sms_out.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include "SMSDispatch.h"
using namespace std;

string sms = "";

void sendSMS(string sms)
{
  SMSDispatch* sPtr=0;
  sPtr->sendSMS(sms);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argv[1])
  {
    string input = argv[1];
    string test = "--author";


 if(input == test)
    {
      cout << "s149113" << endl;
      return 0;
    }
  }

  string line = "";
  string file = "sms_out.txt";
  ifstream myfile(file.c_str());


while(getline(myfile, line))
{
      string idnr, landcode, number, error;
      istringstream linestream(line);

      unsigned short errorcode;

      //Split the sentence
      getline(linestream, idnr, '\t');
      getline(linestream, landcode, ':');
      getline(linestream, number, '\t');
      getline(linestream, error);

  if(idnr == "") break;

  //Make string to int
    try
  {
    errorcode = atoi(error.c_str() );
  }
  catch (exception &)
  {
  }
  //Put together landcode and tlfnumber
  string nr = landcode + number;

  string txt = "Thank you for your vote!";
  if(errorcode == 100) txt = "Invalid question, please try again";
  else if(errorcode == 110) txt = "Sorry, only one vote pr. number";
  else if(errorcode == 200) txt = "Invalid alternative, please try again";
  else if(errorcode == 300) txt = "Missing a statement after other, please try again";
  else if(errorcode == 999) txt = "An error occurred, please try again";

  sms += "{\"ID\":" + idnr + ",\"nr\":" + nr + ",\"txt\":" + "\"" + txt + "\"" + "}\n";
  }
  cout << sms << endl;
  sendSMS(sms);
```

}

//SMSDispatch.h

```
#include <string>
#ifndef SMSDISPATCH_H
#define SMSDISPATCH_H
using namespace std;

class SMSDispatch{
  public:
  virtual void sendSMS(string json);
  };
#endif
```

//SMSDispatch.cpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include "SMSDispatch.h"
 using namespace std;

/*virtual*/void SMSDispatch::sendSMS(string json)
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("sms_out.log");
  myfile << json;
  myfile.close();
}

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you about exactly where the segfault is happening?

Comment: Raw code dumps are not a productive way to ask a question. Learn to use a debugger (read a tutorial, buy a book, attend a class); then narrow down your problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: I don't see you linking with `libSMSDisplay.so`.

Comment: Replace `if(argv[1])` with `if (argc > 1)`. If `argc <= 1` accessing `argv[1]` is illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `sendSMS` function in sms_out.cpp you declare a pointer and initialize it to null-poiter (`0`).  The next line tries to access an object via that pointer and call a member function.  Since the pointer is null (which means it does not point to a valid object), this operation fails wilth a seg.fault

```
void sendSMS(string sms) 
{ 
  SMSDispatch* sPtr=0; // this sets pointer to null
                       // assign the address of a valid `SMSDispatch` object instead
  sPtr->sendSMS(sms); 
}
```

To fix it, forst you need an instance of that type.

Depending on your need you can do

- `SMSDispatch dp; sPtr=&dp;` or
- `sptr=new SMSDispatch;`

In the first case, you could just as well do

```
SMSDispatch dp;
dp.sendSMS(sms);
```

In the secons case you will need to call `delete sptr;` after you don't need the object any more.

Also, note that in order to compile the program, the compiler will need the *definition* of the `SMSDispatch::sendSMS` function.  By including the SMSDispatch.h header, you are only supplying the *declaration*.

You will either need to

- add SMSDispatch.cpp to the g++ invokation for direct bundling of the code or
- link agains the shared library by adding `-lSMSDispatch` to g++ options after building the shared library from SMSDispatch.cpp

Comment: like SMSDispatch* sPtr=&SMSDispatch; ??

Comment: `&SMSDispatch` is not valid as `SMSDispatch` is a type.  You need an instance of that type.  Depending on your need you can do (1)`SMSDispatch dp; sPtr=&dp;` or (2)`sptr=new SMSDispatch;`  in case (1), you could just as well do `SMSDispatch dp; dp.sendSMS(sms);`, in case (2) you will need to call `delete sptr;` after you don't need the object any more.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, but I tried to write SMSDispatch dp; SMSDispatch* sPtr=&dp; sPtr->sendSMS(sms); but then I got a error: undefined reference to `vtable for SMSDispatch'

Comment: That is because you do not link with the generated libSMSDispatch.so  Compile your main program like so: `g++ sms_out.cpp -o sms_out -lSMSDispatch`  (see [here](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/shared_libs_tests.html) for alternatives)  Let me know if this works and I update my answer

Comment: Tried to compile, but just got "cannot find -lSMSDispatch"

Comment: That's an 'l' (small 'L'), not an 'I' (uppercase 'i').  Also, if you are compiling by `g++ sms_out.cpp SMSDispatch.cpp -o sms_out`, you are not linking against a shared library, but bundling all the code into the executable.

Answer (score 9):

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer will cause a segmentation fault:

```
void sendSMS(string sms)
{
  SMSDispatch* sPtr=0;
  sPtr->sendSMS(sms);
}
```

I can't see a reason for using a dynamically allocated object so suggest changing to:

```
void sendSMS(string sms)
{
  SMSDispatch sPtr;
  sPtr.sendSMS(sms);
}
```